# $\operatorname{span}\{AB-BA : A, B \in M_n(\Bbb R)\}$ is the set of all matrices with trace $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

> Let $W$ be the space $$\operatorname{span}\{AB-BA\} ,$$ where A and B are square matrices, and let $H$ be the space of all square matrices of trace $0$. Then prove that $W=H$.

The fact that $W$ is a subset of $H$ is fairly easy to prove. I could prove the converse.

Answer (score 6):

Let $E_{i,j}$ be the matrix with $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and $0$ otherwise.
For $i\ne j$ let $A=E_{i,j}$ and $B=E_{j,j}$. Then  we have $AB=E_{i,j}$ and $BA=0$, hence $E_{i,j}\in W$. It is clear that the $E_{i,j}$ with $i\ne j$ span $H$, hence $H\subseteq W$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but (for $n > 1$ anyway) $E_{11} - E_{22}$ is in $H$ but is not in the span of $\{E_{ij} : i \neq j\}$.

Comment: (One can remedy this by using that $E_{ii} - E_{jj} = E_{ij} E_{ji} - E_{ji} E_{ij} \in H$, and with the matrices $E_{ij}$, $i \neq j$, these matrices span $H$ as desired.)

Comment: The basis that you've made for $H$ is not correct! As @Travis has mentioned, the correct one is:
$$\{ E_{ij} \; \mid \; i \ne j \} \cup \{ E_{ii} - E_{i+1, i+1} \; \mid \; 1 \le i < n \}.$$